# SMTP exception was caught

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This is my password recovery code but I can't find the solution to this problem.

This is the error message:

[image: image1]

Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Hi,<br/> Click on below given link to Reset Your Password<br/>");
sb.Append("<a href=http://localhost:2446/ResetPassLink.aspx?username=" + GetUserEmail(txtEmail.Text));
sb.Append("&email=" + txtEmail.Text + "<a>Click here to change your password</a><br/>");
sb.Append("<b>Thanks</b>,<br> Code Solution <br/>");
sb.Append("thanks");

MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("ToId@gmail.com", txtEmail.Text.Trim(), "Reset Your Password", sb.ToString());

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("FromId@gmail.com", "fromPass");
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
smtp.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out below things, Hope this will help you out.

1. Check your password is right or not.
2. Access for less secure apps, click on this link to allow https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please set EnableSsl to false.

```
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to send mail from Gmail account through third party application, you need to change the security settings of your account.

Login to your Gmail account which you are using in your application
[Change Security settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Select Turn on radio button